# Faster and cleaner way to split a string into a path

Tags: ruby

I have a string like:

```
str = "/some/path/to/some/file.ext"
```

The result should be like:

```
[path, dir, file]
=> ["/some/path/to", "some", "file.ext"]
```

My current code:

```
chunks = str.split '/'
=> ["", "some", "path", "to", "some", "file.ext"]

file = chunks.pop
=> "file.ext"

dir = chunks.pop
=> "some"

path = chunks.join '/'
=> "/some/path/to"
```

But it's ugly and slow.

I also tried regular expressions and `File.split`, but I got an even uglier mess.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pathname`:

```
require 'pathname'

str = "/some/path/to/some/file.ext"

p = Pathname.new str

path, dir, file = [p.dirname.parent, p.parent.basename, p.basename].map(&:to_s)

p( [path, dir, file] )
```

It runs great on all versions.

[**Here you can see it in action**](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=faster-cleaner-way-to-split-a-string-into-path.rb&run=true).

Comment: neat, thanks. regard cibox, it looks great. to be honest, yesterday i added a comment to some question that would be nice to have a service like this for Ruby. someone recommended ideone but i definitely dislike it. thank you